# How to apply ThrowsAdvice for all classes which implement MyInterface

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am new to Spring,learning AOP.
My requirement is i have to apply `ThrowsAdvice` for all classes which implement `MyInterface`.
I have seen many tutorials which explain for single class. But i am looking for all classes which implement `MyInterface`.
I want to apply proxyfactorybean target ref =all interface implementation classes

```
interface  MyInt{
    public String a();
    public String b();
}
```

I want to apply for its implementation classes

```
class Test1 implements MyInt{
    public String a(){ return "some val";}
    public String b(){ return "some val";}
}


class Test2 implements MyInt{
    public String a(){ return "some val";}
    public String b(){ return "some val";}
}
```

In many Toturials they explained

```
<bean id="obj1" class="com.xx.Test1"></bean>  
<bean id="obj2" class="com.xx.Test2"></bean>  
<bean id="ba" class="com.yyy.ThrowsAdvisor"></bean>  

<bean id="proxy"     class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">  
<property name="target" ref="obj1"></property>  
<property name="interceptorNames">  
<list>  
<value>ba</value>  
</list>  
</property>  
</bean>
```

I want to apply `ProxyFactoryBean` target for all classes which implement `MyInt`.

Comment: What version of Spring are you learning ? `<aop>` namespace exists since version 2.0 not speaking of annotations. Are you really required to use explicitely `ProxyFactoryBean` ?

Comment: Well, you forgot to tell what was your advice. But **mine** is simply *read the manual*... Seriously, Spring Reference Manual has a full chapter on AOP with as many examples as you could need. Read it, try something and ask again here if you are stuck anywhere. But your current question is really too broad.

Answer (score 0):

To advise all implementing classes of `MyInt` make use of [`target`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) pointcut designators.

The advice & pointcut should look like something below

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAfterThrowingAdvice {

    @AfterThrowing("target(a.b.c.MyInt)")
    public void doSomething() {
        // log, recover etc.
    }
}
```

Let know in comments if you need any further information.

**P.S.**: It is recommended to learn with latest version of framework; which is `4.2.0` (*at time of writing*).